# Notifying host page when a modal is cancelled (closed) in durandal/knockout

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, durandal

I have a modal with a cancel/close button.

```
<button type="button" class="close" data-bind="click: close" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
```

When the user closes the dialog using cancel, I'd like to notify the host page that the user canceled (as opposed to submitted) the form. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you open a modal in durandal the method returns a promise which is resolved when the dialog is closed.

An example from http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Showing-Message-Boxes-And-Modals.html

```
app.showMessage('This is a message.').then(function(dialogResult){
    //do something with the dialog result here
});
```

When using a custom modal, you create your own dialogResult when you execute dialog.close()

So you would do something like:

```
submit: function() {
    dialog.close( this, "submitted" );
}
close: function() {
    dialog.close( this, "closed" );
}
```

Then in your host page your code would be:

```
app.showDialog('views/dialogs/confirm').then(function(dialogResult){
  if( dialogResult == 'closed' ) 
      // User closed instead of submitting
});
```